# golang recursive function calling itself as a goroutine doesn't work as expected

Tags: recursion, go, goroutine

This recursive function works as expected (returns 5 lines with numbers 5 to 1):

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)
func recur(iter int) {
    if iter <= 0 {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(iter)
    recur(iter-1)
}
func main() {
    recur(5)
}
```

this one does not (returns only 1 line with number 5):

```
    package main
import (
    "fmt"
)
func recur(iter int) {
    if iter <= 0 {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(iter)
    go recur(iter-1)
}
func main() {
    recur(5)
}
```

The difference is that in the second implementation, function calls itself as a goroutine. (line `go recur(iter-1)` )

So can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: You need a cycle of time when you use go routine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you make everything asynchronous, there is nothing in `main` to wait on. You have to explicitly wait on the go routines so your program does not exit before the recursive process finishes.

Use [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) or something similar for synchronization. Example ([On Play](https://play.golang.org/p/OqWclTzNEJ)):

```
func recur(iter int, g *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer g.Done()
    if iter <= 0 {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(iter)
    go recur(iter-1, g)
}

func main() {
    g := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    runs := 5
    g.Add(runs)
    recur(runs, g)
    g.Wait()
}
```

Comment: When traversing a graph you have an unknown amount of branches in each recursion. Possible refactor: call `Add(1)` before each `recur()`, including main. See example: https://play.golang.org/p/OuZVgowAbt

Answer (score 1):

Your programming is exiting before all the goroutines finish.  The simplest way to see this work is as follows.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func recur(iter int) {
    if iter <= 0 {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(iter)
    go recur(iter - 1)
}
func main() {
    recur(5)
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/XC3oplghBi)

Rather than sleeping, however, you may want to pass a `sync.WaitGroup` through to your function.

Comment: Thanks. Just realized that myself and added the same sleep line to confirm:)